# Yii's asseets folder with no write access

Tags: php, permissions, yii, orchestra

I am trying to deploy a PHP Yii app to Orchestra (https://www.engineyard.com/products/orchestra/). The platform, like I think many cloud-based platform, doesn't allow write permissions.

I've managed to get around the 'runtime' directory that Yii requires by putting it in the system's tmp folder. However I'm stuck with the 'assets' folder. Yii requires a writable AND publicly accessible folder.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: In that specific case the issue arose with Yii forms, yiiactiveform.js was loaded from the assets folder. For now I've simply copied it to the hardcoded 'js' folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii requires somewhere to put the files from within the core or modules to be publicly accessible.

If this isn't possible you might have to go through and manually grab each js/css file your going to want, place them in the folders required and use [scriptMap](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance#minimizing-script-files) to map these back or block them and include them yourself.

There's lots of documentation around [Client Script](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript) which is what handles all this.